# AWS Amplify doesn't delete user from Identity Pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have noticed that Amplify's `Auth.deleteUser()` function doesn't delete a user's identity from the identity pool, even though it does successfully delete the user from the user pool.

Is this intentional or an oversight? Is it best practice to manually delete identities from an identity pool or are they generally just allowed to accumulate even after their linked users are deleted from the user pool or other 3rd party account provider?

I know that identity pools support an unlimited number of identities, but I would still imagine it's best practice to delete identities when their linked accounts are deleted right?

Any guidance on this subject would be appreciated. Ultimately I just want to know if it's best practice for me to be using the SDK's DeleteIdentitiesCommand to delete user identities from the identity pool once their associated account is deleted from the user pool, or if this is supposed to be happening automatically, and therefore indicates that my configuration is flawed somewhere.

Comment: From the user pool or identity pool? I see successful deletion from the user pool, but not the identity pool. The identity id remains, and still shows that it has a linked login even though the user is gone from the user pool.

Comment: Could you add your function code? Does this function code have a try/catch block that `console.error()` the potential issue?

Comment: Thanks Luke. The code is literally no more complicated than a try-catch with `Auth.deleteUser()` inside. It logs the error in the catch, and logs the response on success. In my testing, it never errors, it succeeds and just outputs 'SUCCESS'. The user is successfully gone from the user pool, but not the identity pool. If I search for the user's identity id in the identity pool, it produces a result viewable in the AWS Console identity browser.